# Why isn't next function in my express code working properly?

Tags: node.js, express, synchronous

So basically I am trying to carry out function synchronously using next but Its not happening synchronously: Route.JS

```
 router.post('/era',function(req,res,next){
        console.log("got request");

    controlleri.book(req,res,next);
    booking_controller.book(req,res);
    console.log("done in server.js");
    next();

});
```

`controlleri.book` and `booking_controller.book` both have database calls but 
Inspite of adding next() in `controlleri.book`, `booking_controller.book` starts executing before next  being called in the first function.
Tell me if both functions are needed.

Edit:

Tried using async library still its not going synchrounosly Code:

```
router.post('/era',function(req,res){
    console.log("got request");

async.series([

function(callback){
    console.log("hi");
    controlleri.book(req,res);
    callback(null);
},
function(callback){
    console.log("hias");
    booking_controller.book(req,res);
    callback(null);
}
```

]);

Second function begins before completing First one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your functions take `req`, `res` and `next` as their arguments which is a signature for a middleware function. Further, express middleware is executed in order. Why not just make each of your functions into their own middleware and in the execution order you need them in?

```
// POST executes controlleri.book
// then booking_controller.book,
// then the log code
router.post('/era', controlleri.book, booking_controller.book, function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("done in server.js");
});
```

This way, `next` within `controlleri.book` will be `booking_controller.book`, and `next` in `booking_controller.book` will be the last method that logs `"done in server.js"`

Comment: Ok thanks this works but how would I do the same using async library ,async.series function

Answer (score 0):

Use [aync library](https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback) for doinf operations syncronously.

next() is a middleware which tells that the request shouldn't be returned but there are more functions to be applied on the request.The functions it gets to operate are performed asynchronously because that's node's default behaviour.

```
async.series([
    controlleri.book(callback){
        // do some stuff ...
        callback(null, 'one');
    },
    booking_controller.book(callback){
        // do some more stuff ...
        callback(null, 'two');
    }
],
// optional callback
function(err, results){
    // results is now equal to ['one', 'two']

});
```

async.series takes an array of functions to be performed in order (synchronously). The callback passed in each function is mandatory.

Comment: I tried Using async library I edited the question but still Its not going in the flow I want

Comment: You want controlleri.book() to be executed before booking_controller.book() ?

Comment: Yes @Himani I controlleri.book() to finish before staring next booking_controller.book()

Comment: Try the updated code, where req, res arguments are removed from functions to be called. Also, what arguments do controlleri.book() and booking_controller.book() take?

Comment: They take req,res variables and both are necesassry

Comment: How are you determining the 2nd function starts before completion of 1st function? The documentation says it runs synchronously.